# Angular js: spliting date,month and time using angular filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to split up date,month (in words) and time from a timestamp in a `ng-repeat`

```
$scope.notes.forEach(function(notes){
     $scope.notes.date = new Date(notes.date);
    });
```

In my view am using angular filter

```
 <div ng-repeat="note in notes">
Date: {{note.date | date:'dd'}}
Month:{{note.date | date:'mm'}}
</div>
```

This works fine ,but i need two more additional things

1.Month is in words eg: (March)

2.Time parameter eg:2 pm

Is it possible with angular filter?

Note:
Sample timestamp `2016-06-02T16:14:34+0530`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Month, you can filter it by using the following:

```
Month:{{note.date | date: 'MMMM'}}
```

Time can be filtered in two ways depending on how you want to format:

```
Time:{{note.date | date: 'hh:a'}}
```

OR

```
Time:{{note.date | date: 'h:a'}}
```

Here's a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to the documentation on date filtering.

Comment: its worked ,one more thing how can i decide am or pm

Comment: Try the edit. I believe this is how you add a second filter. The `'a'` is the filter for AM/PM

Comment: I had to update the answer again because I had the wrong syntax. Based on other answers from SO there are accepted answers using the corrected syntax for multiple time filters. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662511/displaying-time-in-am-pm-format-with-angular-grid)